# How to create inline raw HTML element in CommonMark?

Tags: html, markdown, commonmark

I am trying out CommonMark at http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/

I want the following HTML output, i.e. `Foo` and `Baz` are emphasized
but `Bar` is not emphasized.

```
<p><em>Foo</em> *Bar* <em>Baz</em></p>
```

I tried various inputs, but none of them works. I am providing a list of
various CommonMark input and HTML output below for attempts that did not
work.

1. Input:

   ```
   *Foo* *Bar* *Baz*
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   <p><em>Foo</em> <em>Bar</em> <em>Baz</em></p>
   ```

   Result: Of course, this does not work!
2. Input:

   ```
   *Foo* <span>*Bar*</span> *Baz*
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   <p><em>Foo</em> <span><em>Bar</em></span> <em>Baz</em></p>
   ```

   Result: `Bar` is still emphasized. This is in agreement with
   point 7 of the
   [spec regarding HTML blocks](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#html-blocks)
   where it is clearly mentioned that the `<span>` must occur on its
   own line.
3. Input:

   ```
   *Foo*
   <span>
   *Bar*
   </span>
   *Baz*
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   <p><em>Foo</em>
   <span>
   <em>Bar</em>
   </span>
   <em>Baz</em></p>
   ```

   Result: `Baz` is still emphasized. This time `<span>` occurred on
   its own line. Why did it still not work?

How can I achieve the desired result while conforming to CommonMark?

Comment: @Chris Oops! You are right. I have fixed the desired output now in the question. The desired output is: `<p><em>Foo</em> *Bar* <em>Baz</em></p>`.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#backslash-escapes) explains that

> Escaped characters are treated as regular characters and do not have their usual Markdown meanings

This should give the output you want:

```
*Foo* \*Bar* *Baz*
```